# How to use AJAX to display the data retrieved by html-don?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, simple-html-dom

I have 3 files: index.html, parse.php, profile.html

index.html: It has a form, where I give the link of profile.html and with the html-dom parsing in parse.php, I should get all the data on the same page, i.e index.html.

I am new to AJAX and did not use it till now.

How should I go through on doing the operation?

index.html:

```
<form action="parse.php" method="post" id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="uurl"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

parse.php:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = $_POST['uurl'];

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find("span[class=full-name]") as $key => $name){
echo $name."<br>";

}
```

script:

```
<script> 

        $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Please post your code here.

Comment: Use javascript to send your request to the server: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and then use javascript to change your dom.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Edited the question with codes.

Comment: and now what you do in that foreach? and where do you want to put the data, what you parsed?

Comment: You do it the same way as you would do it without ajax. The only difference is that the results will be displayed on the same page instead of a new one.

Comment: @joelharkes said everything. You should also return the result you get in your parse.php and then catch it with `$post()` to display result wherever you want.
So, instead of doing `echo` in your loop `for`, you add those data to the `$name` variable, and return it. Then, in you DOM you catch this by $post() and you're done.

Comment: @jeroen How do I display it on the same page?

Comment: How do you display it now? You extract the code that parses and displays, put that in a separate script and call that using for example jQuery's `$.ajax()` method. You should start with the jQuery manual.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I want to display $name

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<form action="parse.php" id="myform" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="uurl" id="uurl"><br>
<input type="button" value="" >
</form>

<ul class="results"></ul>
```

Include jquery script tag, and add the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform button').on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/parse.php', { uurl: $('#uurl').val() }).done(function(a) {
            var html = '';
            if (a.results && a.results.length > 0) {
                for (var i in a.results) {
                    html += '<li>' + a.results[i] + '</li>';
                }
            } else {
                html += '<li class="error">No Results Found</li>';
            }
            $('ul.results').html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

In parse.php:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = $_POST['uurl'];

$results = array();
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find("span[class=full-name]") as $key => $name){
    $results[] = $name;
}

echo json_encode(array('results' => $results));
```

Comment: You might have to modify the code inside the getJSON done() function to suit your needs.

Comment: And what if I have to retrieve another data in parse.php. Say, $location. How would that go in array results??

Comment: I got this error from the code: Warning: json_encode(): recursion detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\parse.php on line 48

Comment: Umm that has something to do with your code.. the code I gave for parse.php doesn't have any recursion?

Answer (score 0):

So technically you aren't even using AJAX. Ajax is based on javascript and I don't see any javascript in your code.

Also, from what I understand, you don't need any PHP code to do what you're trying to.

Here is how you would do it. This would be the HTML.

```
<form action="parse.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="uurl" id="uurl"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-form">
</form>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

And then you would need this javascript:

```
var $url = $('#uurl');
var $button = $('#submit-form');
var $container = $('#container');

$button.on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default form submission.
    $.get($url.val(), function(response){
        $container.html(response);
    })
});
```

I have used jQuery for clarity, but it definitely not required.

Comment: It didn't work. It still goes to parse.php and displays on that page.

Comment: That would be a problem with your php setup. Ideally, the AJAX page should just fetch profile.html as is, and then you can just inject the HTML from the profile.html into the container div. Try, doing the same thing, but without the form. Try fetching the HTML and injecting it into the container div with jQuery.

Comment: I am using echo to print data on the parse.php page. And profile.html is where we parse the data from. This parsing is done in parse.php.